# Using GetOpenFile and GetKeyState in console application

Tags: winapi, console-application

I am experiencing odd behavior when using GetKeyState (or GetAsyncKeyState, for that matter) in a console app.  One aspect of the app is to ask the user for a file to open using GetFileOpen.  At the end of the program, GetKeyState monitors the state of the spacebar.  The GetKeyState (or GetAsyncKeyState) function never sets the high order bit whenever the spacebar is pressed.  If I do not call GetOpenFile and then monitor GetKeyState, all works as expected.

Here are the two basic scenarios.

Scenario 1:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char filename[ 512 ] = {0};
    OPENFILENAME ofn = {0};
    int filenameSize = 512;
    char title[1000] = {0};

    strcpy(title, "Open File");

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = null;
    ofn.lpstrFile = filename;
    ofn.nMaxFile = filenameSize;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "All files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpfnHook = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = title;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

    GetOpenFileName(&ofn);  // filename obtained

    WaitForSpaceBar(); // return value's upper bit is never set for 
                       // GetKeyState(VK_SPACE);
    return 0;
}
```

Scenario 2:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WaitForSpaceBar(); // returns immediately after spacebar is pressed
    return 0;
}
```

WaitForSpaceBar code

```
void WaitForSpaceBar()
{
#define KEY_PRESSED_FLAG 1
    SHORT spacePressed = GetKeyState(VK_SPACE);

    printf("\nPress spacebar to continue...\n");
    while (!(spacePressed & KEY_PRESSED_FLAG))
    {
        Sleep(1);
        spacePressed = GetKeyState(VK_SPACE);

        // for debugging purposes only
        printf("spacePressed = 0x%04x\n", spacePressed);     
    }
}
```

The first scenario outputs "spacePressed = 0x0000" indefinitely regardless of how many times I press the spacebar.

The second scenario outputs "spacePressed = 0x0000" until the spacebar is actually pressed.  Once pressed, the output is "spacePressed = 0xffffff81", and the program terminates.

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: You cannot reliably use USER32 functions in a console application. USER32 targets the GUI subsystem of Windows. `GetKeyState` requires that an application reads key messages from its message queue. A message queue is a GUI application concept.

Comment: Try `GetAsyncKeyState` instead. `GetKeyState` returns the state as it was when the last message was processed, not the state as it is now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.  The spacebar press is detected for me in both scenarios.  Windows 7, VS 2010, Debug and Release builds, 32- and 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

The GetKeyState function is useless if your are not pumping message.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx):

> Remarks
>
> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads
>   key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the
>   interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the
>   GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information.

Use the following code for your `WaitForSpaceBar` function (note the new value for `KEY_PRESSED_FLAG`):

```
void WaitForSpaceBar()
{
    SHORT spacePressed = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE);
#define KEY_PRESSED_FLAG 0x8000
    printf("\nPress spacebar to continue...\n");
    while (!(spacePressed & KEY_PRESSED_FLAG))
    {
        Sleep(1);
        spacePressed = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE);

        // for debugging purposes only
        printf("spacePressed = 0x%04x\n", spacePressed);     
    }
}
```

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy It's the bit 0 for GetKeyState and the bit 15 for GetAsyncKeyState. Sleep is highly recommended in such code, beware the burning CPUs!

Comment: You're right about the bit.  I misread.  Nevertheless, the code works fine for me without the Sleep, so I'm still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy and what is the CPU usage if you sit here without hitting space?

Comment: I have no argument with putting in Sleep to reduce the CPU load.  I thought your answer was implying that the Sleep causes messages to pump and thereby enables GetKeyState.  That's not the case.  The code in the question works for me without changes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it looks like GetKeyState is only meaningful when your thread is pumping messages and calling it in response to a keyboard message.

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue.

I suspect that GetOpenFile spins up its own thread and that thread somehow becomes the main UI thread for your process (because it's the only one doing GUI work).

If you're using Windows API calls, you may as well use something console-specific like [ReadConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Update**:  I pasted the question code into VS 2010, and cannot reproduce the problem.  The GetKeyState function is working as expected regardless of whether GetOpenFileName was called.

Comment: `GetOpenFileName()` displays a modal dialog and thus processes dialog messages in the same thread that calls it.  It does not create its own thread.

Comment: Hmm, not so fast, he never called CoInitializeEx().

Comment: @HansPassant: You don't have to initialize COM to use the traditional Win32 APIs.  At least, I can't find any documentation that says you need to, nor have I had any problem doing such things in my own code without ever initializing COM.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, mode modal dialogs run on the calling thread.  But that's an implementation detail.  Peeking with the debugger during the dialog shows that several additional threads are created, including a couple Win32 Threads, one of which is pumping messages.

Comment: That does not mean the dialog uses threads to process dialog messages or keyboard states, though. Those extra threads are typically created by the Shell for its own internal work, especially when the dialog is running in Explorer mode. In that mode, `GetOpenFileName()` displays Shell objects, which are implemented as COM objects. So calling `OleInitialize/Ex()` or `CoInitialize/Ex()` is important.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  "That does not mean the dialog uses threads to process dialog messages or keyboard states, though."  Agreed.  I just said that it might, and that there's some evidence that it might be doing that.  The point is, it's an implementation detail, and it could explain the claimed behavior.  I can't actually reproduce the claimed behavior, so I suspect the question has left out an important detail.